# Unable to send out emails from my Linux Host

Tags: email, postfix, sendmail, smtp, mailx

Unable to send out emails from my Linux Host. Below is the command I try:

```
echo "This is the message body and contains the message" | sudo mailx -v  mypunnq@gmail.com  -s "This is the subject"
```

or

```
mail -s "Test Subject" mypunnq@gmail.com < /home/system/mailbody.txt
```

Output:

```
Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <root>.
```

Here is the Running process.

```
$ ps -ef | grep postfix
postfix   2993 30866  0 19:15 ?        00:00:00 pickup -l -t unix -u
system    4399   594  0 19:28 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postfix
root     30866     1  0  2020 ?        00:00:19 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
postfix  30868 30866  0  2020 ?        00:00:05 qmgr -l -t unix -u
```

Here is the telnet showing port 25 is LISTENING on my system:

```
$ telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 efendibey_live.localdomain ESMTP Postfix
```

Here is the output of `mailq`:

```
$ mailq
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
AE3BF1FC5       606 Sun Feb  7 19:15:10  system@efendibey_live.localdomain
            (connect to mx2.zoho.com[136.143.191.44]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         mohtashim@digiklug.com

7410B47CA       602 Sun Feb  7 19:18:57  system@efendibey_live.localdomain
(delivery temporarily suspended: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
                                         mypunnq@gmail.com

3EC5F1EC2       474 Sun Feb  7 19:13:34  system@efendibey_live.localdomain
            (connect to mx2.zoho.com[136.143.191.44]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         mohtashim@digiklug.com

456251FC6       656 Sun Feb  7 19:18:04  system@efendibey_live.localdomain
            (connect to mx2.zoho.com[136.143.191.44]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         mohtashim@digiklug.com

1CB9D48FB       652 Sun Feb  7 19:20:04  system@efendibey_live.localdomain
(connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
                                         mypunnq@gmail.com

1FE9B450F       652 Sun Feb  7 19:19:45  system@efendibey_live.localdomain
(connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
                                         mypunnq@gmail.com

B180025B5       654 Sun Feb  7 19:25:25  root@efendibey_live.localdomain
(delivery temporarily suspended: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
                                         mypunnq@gmail.com
```

Update:

The outbound port is also open and connecting:

```
$ telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 108.177.119.26...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP g24si11485107edh.82 - gsmtp
```

Once I fire the command to sent out an email I can see it in the `mailQ` and then disappear from the Queue, however, I still do not receive the mail in my inbox.

```
[system@efendibey_live ~]$ echo "This is the message body and contains the message" | sudo mailx -v  mohtashim@digiklug.com -s "This is the subject"
Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <root>.

[system@live ~]$ mailq
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
3723C16BC*      658 Mon Feb  8 13:37:13  root@ebey_live.localdomain
                                         mohtashim@digiklug.com

-- 1 Kbytes in 1 Request.

[system@live ~]$ mailq
Mail queue is empty
[system@live ~]$
```

The below is the output from  `tail -f /var/log/maillog` for a single mail send command.

```
Feb  8 15:29:43 Efendibey_Live postfix/pickup[10591]: E4F5F16A9: uid=0 from=<root>
Feb  8 15:29:43 Efendibey_Live postfix/cleanup[18223]: E4F5F16A9: message-id=<20210208152943.E4F5F16A9@efendibey_live.localdomain>
Feb  8 15:29:43 Efendibey_Live postfix/qmgr[1193]: E4F5F16A9: from=<root@efendibey_live.localdomain>, size=467, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  8 15:29:45 Efendibey_Live postfix/smtp[18225]: E4F5F16A9: to=<mohtashim@digiklug.com>, relay=mx.zoho.com[136.143.191.44]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0.03/0.01/0.67/0.51, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host mx.zoho.com[136.143.191.44] said: 541 5.7.1 Mail rejected due to antispam policy (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Feb  8 15:29:45 Efendibey_Live postfix/cleanup[18223]: 468D216BC: message-id=<20210208152945.468D216BC@efendibey_live.localdomain>
Feb  8 15:29:45 Efendibey_Live postfix/qmgr[1193]: 468D216BC: from=<>, size=2472, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  8 15:29:45 Efendibey_Live postfix/bounce[18227]: E4F5F16A9: sender non-delivery notification: 468D216BC
Feb  8 15:29:45 Efendibey_Live postfix/qmgr[1193]: E4F5F16A9: removed
Feb  8 15:29:45 Efendibey_Live postfix/local[18228]: 468D216BC: to=<root@efendibey_live.localdomain>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Feb  8 15:29:45 Efendibey_Live postfix/qmgr[1193]: 468D216BC: removed
```

I even tried the `-f legitimateemail@gmail.com` option in `mailx` but still, no emails received.

Here is my `/etc/hosts` entry

```
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

127.0.0.1 guest
::1       guest

127.0.0.1 Efendibey_Live
::1       Efendibey_Live
```

Can you please suggest how can I get emails to work from my Linux host?

Comment: The email is being bounced by the recepient: `Mail rejected due to antispam policy (in reply to RCPT TO command)`.  My guess is that `myhostname` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` is  `efendibey_live.localdomain`  The `.localdomain` tld wont be accepted by external MTAs because when they do a DNS lookup, they don't get a result.  You need to ensure your DNS points to your server and ensure your postfix uses the same name.

Comment: @Stewart i dont have myhostname specified in `main.cf` See here: `# grep myhostname /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep -v '^#'
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
`   I also updated the original host with `/etc/hosts` entries

Comment: Yep, that sounds like a problem.  I'll write an answer for that specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an update you showed your `/var/log/mail.log` contained this:

```
Feb  8 15:29:43 Efendibey_Live postfix/qmgr[1193]: E4F5F16A9: 
     from=<root@efendibey_live.localdomain>, size=467, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  8 15:29:45 Efendibey_Live postfix/smtp[18225]: E4F5F16A9:
     to=<mohtashim@digiklug.com>, 
     relay=mx.zoho.com[136.143.191.44]:25, 
     delay=1.2, delays=0.03/0.01/0.67/0.51, dsn=5.7.1, 
     status=bounced (host mx.zoho.com[136.143.191.44] said: 
         541 5.7.1 Mail rejected due to antispam policy (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

This means your message was sent successfully, but it was rejected by the recipient.  What's also interesting is the `from=` address.  It looks like your domain is `efendibey_live.localdomain`.  If the recipient can't do a DNS lookup of your domain, then they will often reject your email.

When `postfix` is configured, it uses the output of `hostname -f` to set everything up.  That's a function of your machine name, and of the DNS entry for your machine.  The solution is to update your `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

My stuff looks like this:

```
$ hostname -f
mail.example.com

$ cat /etc/hostname
mail.example.com

$ host -t mx example.com
example.com is handled by 10 MAIL.example.com

$ host -t a mail.example.com
mail.example.com has address aa.bb.cc.dd

$ cat /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep myhostname
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
myhostname = example.com
mydestination = $myhostname, example.com, mail.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help ... this works !! however, My emails endup in SPAM. Anyway to resolve that?

Comment: Go to `mail-tester.com` and send them an email.  They'll give you a report of why your email may be rejected or marked as spam.  It's probably related to SPF and DKIM DNS records.

Answer (score 4):

Credit for this answer belongs to [linuxbabe](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu) which I used recently when I had the same problem.

Run the following command on your mail server to check if port 25 (outbound) is blocked.

```
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
```

If it’s not blocked, you would see messages like below, which indicates a connection is successfully established. (Hint: Type in `quit` and press Enter to close the connection.)

```
Trying 74.125.68.26...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP y22si1641751pll.208 - gsmtp
```

If port 25 (outbound) is blocked, you would see something like:

```
Trying 2607:f8b0:400e:c06::1a...
Trying 74.125.195.27...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

In this case, your Postfix can’t send emails to other SMTP servers. Ask your ISP/hosting provider to open the outbound port 25 for you. If they refuse your request, you need to [set up SMTP relay to bypass port 25 blocking](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/postfix-smtp-relay) or use a VPS like [ScalaHosting](https://www.linuxbabe.com/scalahosting-self-managed-cloud-vps) that doesn’t block port 25.

Some folks might be asking, “Can I change port 25 to another port to bypass blocking”? The answer is no. Changing the port works only when you control both the server-side and client-side. When Postfix sends emails, it acts as the SMTP client. The recipient’s mail server acts as the SMTP server. **You don’t have control over the receiving SMTP server**. SMTP servers are listening on port 25 to receive emails. They expect SMTP clients to hit port 25. There’s no other port for receiving emails. If your Postfix don’t connect to port 25 of the receiving SMTP server, you won’t be able to send emails.

Comment: I got the outbound port opened but the email is still not received @Stewart Output here: `$ telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 108.177.119.26...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP g24si11485107edh.82 - gsmtp
`

Comment: This means your email is probably being sent, but refused by the recipient.  Send a mail, then post the output of `tail /var/log/mail.log`.  It may be that you don't have a PTR address, or the `hostname` doesn't match your `MX` or `A` DNS records. Some MTAs reject messages if your Postfix does not provide FQDN in smtpd banner. Some MTAs even query DNS to see if FQDN in the smtpd banner resolves to the IP of your mail server.

Comment: @Steward I updated my original post with the contents of `tail /var/log/maillog`